# Android app links intent-filter with wildcard subdomain not verified

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I have app links in my app for two subdomains.

Assetlinks.json is already placed in our host's well-known directory and returns proper json.
When I use the following intent-filter, everything works fine.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

> Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:27 scheme:"https"
> hosts:"www.example.com" package:"com.example.seven". [CONTEXT
> service_id=244 ] Verification 27 complete. Success:true. Failed
> hosts:. [CONTEXT service_id=244 ]

But when I try to set up our intent filter for multiple subdomains like this:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

> The verification is never passed: Verifying IntentFilter.
> verificationId:26 scheme:"https" hosts:"example.com"
> package:"com.example.seven". [CONTEXT service_id=244 ] Verification 26
> complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:example.com. [CONTEXT
> service_id=244 ]

Has anyone experienced this issue and what can be done?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was, that assetlinks.json was stored under
[www.example.com/.well-known/](https://www.example.com/.well-known/)
which turned out to be a different place from
[example.com/.well-known/](https://www.example.com/.well-known/)

Using wildcard subdomain app tried to verify 2 domains:
[www.example.com](https://www.example.com/.well-known/) and [example.com](https://www.example.com/.well-known/). And failed with the second, what failed the verification in general.

Basically, [www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json](https://www.example.com/.well-known/) was reached via chain of redirections [image]

This is why it seemed to me, that [example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json](https://www.example.com/.well-known/) was present.

And app links [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#publish-json) says:

> The assetlinks.json file must be accessible without any redirects (no
> 301 or 302 redirects).

So if you want to use wildcard subdomains, **make sure to locate your assetlinks.json
under exactly [example.com](https://www.example.com/.well-known/) domain**.